# Is 'poltroon' omitted after the word 'made'?

Tags: subject-auxiliary-inversion, exclamatives

Here's a sample from 'Jane Eyre':

> I now stood in the empty hall; before me was the breakfast-room door, and I stopped, intimidated and trembling.  What a **miserable** little poltroon had fear, engendered of unjust punishment, **made** of me in those days!

1. After the word 'miserable', is ‘that’, which is a conjunction implying the cause of 'miserable', omitted?
2. After the word 'made', is 'poltroon' omitted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, nothing is omitted, and the sentence is perfectly formed. Fear, engendered of unjust punishment, had made of Jane a miserable little poltroon. ‘What a . . .’ is a fairly common way of introducing an exclamation. Less complex examples are ‘What a fool I was!’, ‘What a lovely day it has been!’ and ‘What a handsome boy he has become!’
‘Poltroon’ cannot be repeated after ‘made’: it has already been mentioned as the object of ‘had made’.

Answer (score 11):

Let's simplify things a little.  "Engendered of just punishment" can be removed without affecting how we parse the rest of the sentence.  We can also remove "in those days":

> What a [[miserable little] poltroon] had fear made of me!

Now things are starting to look a little simpler.

1. No, "that" is not omitted.  I've bracketed the phrase "miserable little" which modifies "poltroon".  "Miserable little" is a semi-common phrase that modifies a noun.  It's usually a disparaging phrase; you could say, for example, "You miserable little wretch!"
   　
   Let's try taking out "miserable little" to simplify it a little further for question two.
2. No, "poltroon" is not omitted.  Let's try inserting it into our simplified version:

> What a poltroon had fear made of me!
>
> *What a poltroon had fear made *poltroon* of me!

This isn't grammatical.  So how do we understand the phrase?  Barrie England's answer compares it to "What a fool I was!" and I think that's a perfect comparison.  Another way to understand it is to turn it around:

> Fear had made a poltroon of me!

Without the "What . . . " rhetorical device, this sounds a little silly, but I hope it demonstrates how the phrase fits together.

Comment: I think this is a good simplification/deconstruction. It might have been better to replace literary/antiquated *poltroon* with something more current *(coward, wimp, sissy, baby)* to remove the pointless distraction. Apart from anything else, if it's *not* mentioned here, sooner or later someone is going to ask if he can reasonably call his mate a *poltroon* for being embarrassed to ask a girl out, say. Whatever - given OP thought maybe there should be a second "poltroon", he clearly needed it to be fully broken down, so this is the best level of response.

Comment: It might help to examine the sentence in a slightly more standard order by replacing *what* with *such*, "Engendered of unjust punishment, fear had made such a miserable little poltroon of me in those days!" The exclamatory *what* needs the original, inverted sentence order.